# Entity Framework with thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, entity-framework, .net-5

I'm facing a problem that has been discussed in many topics and has many solutions, but I still haven't found an optimal solution for my project. I am making a Discord bot, and of course there will be lots of threads and huge amounts of data going in and out of my database. One of the problems I had, I will simulate it in console app below:

```
static void TestDatabase()
{
    var DbContext = new PostgreSQLContext(ToPostgresConnectionString());

    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            var data = await DbContext.Guilds
                .Where(x => x.GuildID == (398887563366105099 + i))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (data == null)
            {
                DbContext.Guilds.Add(new GuildModel()
                {
                    GuildID = (398887563366105099 + i),
                    GuildName = "ABCAAAAAAAAA",
                    CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    OwnerID = 398887563366105099
                });
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    });

    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {

        for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            var data = await DbContext.Guilds
                .Where(x => x.GuildID == (398887563366105099 + i))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (data == null)
            {
                DbContext.Guilds.Add(new GuildModel()
                {
                    GuildID = (398887563366105099 + i),
                    GuildName = "ABCAAAAAAAAA",
                    CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    OwnerID = 398887563366105099
                });
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run the above code I get problem with safe-thread on 2nd Task:

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnConfiguring' since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

After a while, some people told me that I should use (using) in each Task to ensure that they do not collide when using the same Context class. I edited my code:

```
static void TestDatabase()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using var DbContext = new PostgreSQLContext(ToPostgresConnectionString());
        for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            var data = await DbContext.Guilds
                .Where(x => x.GuildID == (398887563366105099 + i))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (data == null)
            {
                DbContext.Guilds.Add(new GuildModel()
                {
                    GuildID = (398887563366105099 + i),
                    GuildName = "ABCAAAAAAAAA",
                    CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    OwnerID = 398887563366105099
                });
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    });

    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using var DbContext = new PostgreSQLContext(ToPostgresConnectionString());
        for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            var data = await DbContext.Guilds
                .Where(x => x.GuildID == (398887563366105099 + i))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (data == null)
            {
                DbContext.Guilds.Add(new GuildModel()
                {
                    GuildID = (398887563366105099 + i),
                    GuildName = "ABCAAAAAAAAA",
                    CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    OwnerID = 398887563366105099
                });
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run the above code, there will be a problem that because the test data of these 2 tasks are the same, but the Task above has not been saved to the database, the 2nd Task has started to get the data and it still save. Then the unique index at the database will give an error.

> Why do both codes have to run on the same data?

It will pull from the server and will process before writing to the database and marking it as done processing so that it won't be processed again next time (The above is just a simulation, not the actual application). Other information:

```
internal partial class GuildModel
{
    public long GuildID { get; set; }
    public string GuildName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public long OwnerID { get; set; }
}

class PostgreSQLContext : DbContext
{
    private string ConnectionStringProvider { get; }
    public PostgreSQLContext(string ConnectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionStringProvider = ConnectionString;
    }
    public PostgreSQLContext(DbContextOptions<PostgreSQLContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    internal virtual DbSet<GuildModel> Guilds { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(this.ConnectionStringProvider);
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GuildModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Guilds").HasKey(x => x.GuildID);
            entity.Property(e => e.GuildID).HasColumnName("GuildID")
                .HasColumnType("bigint").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.GuildName).HasColumnName("GuildName")
                .HasColumnType("text");
            entity.Property(e => e.CreationDate).HasColumnName("CreationDate")
                .HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.OwnerID).HasColumnName("OwnerID")
                .HasColumnType("bigint").IsRequired();
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.GuildID).IsUnique(true);
        });
    }
}

public static string ToPostgresConnectionString()
{
    var csb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Host = "localhost",
        Port = 5434,

        Database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        Username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

        SslMode = SslMode.Disable,
        TrustServerCertificate = true
    };
    return csb.ConnectionString;
}
```

I use: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL (5.0.10), .Net 5.0

Comment: "*Why do both codes have to run on the same data?*" - Because your are closing over the loop variable. However you have bigger design problems I fear. Though i am finding it hard to see what the actual problem is you are trying to solve, and why you are using tasks like this in the first place

Comment: More specifically, when the user grant a permision to lower user the trigger will notify to my bot and the bot will get the lastest 10 record to read and process and then save it to the database, indicates that this data has been processed and stored. However, granting permission in Discord by clicking the check box if granting 100 permissions, there will be 100 times when the bot gets the data to read and all happens at almost the same time, so I simulated it by design for loop to test and check.

Comment: In fact, each time bot get the data, it will return 10 records, of which there are 9 records shown in the previous time and 1 latest record. I can't (still can) get only the latest record to process because the API server response can be slow and make the data unreliable, maybe the first get will return 1 latest record, but it of the 5th because of slow response speed.

Comment: And what happens when in the 2nd time there are 9 data in the 1st time and when the 1st time has not been saved, it continues to process and save to the database